# Magento 2 how to add ttl attribute to referenceBlock?

Tags: magento2, layout, catalogsearch

I need to add ttl="3600" to a referenceBloc, I would override the whole catalogsearch_result_index.xml but there are some third parties modules that crash if I override the whole file.

so I tried this inside VENDOR/MODULE/view/frontend/layout/catalogsearch_result_index.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="search.result">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="attributes" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="ttl" xsi:type="string">3600</item>
                </argument> 
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
```

but I don't know if it's working in this way.

If I directly add ttl="3600" in the block declaration of the file on vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/view/frontend/layout/catalogsearch_result_index.xml

It seems that works, but this is a ReferenceBlock and I don't know how to do it this way.

Thanks and greetings!

Answer (score 0):

Simply use as below.

No need to pass ttl as argument.

```
<referenceBlock name="search.result" ttl="3600" />
```

Comment: no it does not work like this, I tried it and the error message was "no ttl is supporte on referenceBlock", also on Magento 2 documentation it says there are only 2 attributes for referenceBlock, remove and display.